# jScrollPane snap to grid / div

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I was wondering if there is a way you can have like a snap to grid /div with the fullbrowser scroll bar jscrollpane..

so lets say i have:

10 divs and jsrollpane (full browser scroll)

i want my scroller to snap on to one of those divs depending on wich div is closest to my scrollbar

is there a way to achieve this?